# Add times in buffer

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Suppose I have an emacs buffer which contains times in the format minutes'seconds'' and in the format minutes' as well as seconds'' for example 5'30'', 6'15'', 10' and 1''. Is it possible to add all times in the buffer automatically with output (in the minibuffer) in the format minutes'seconds'' (here = 21'46'')?

Comment: Should that be `6'15''`?

Comment: Oh, yes. I change it. Additionally I want also times in the format minutes' (I forgot this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
(defun add-times ()                 
  (interactive)                                
  (let ((minutes 0) (seconds 0))     
    (save-excursion                        
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\([0-9]+\\)'\\('\\)?" (point-max) t)
        (if (match-string 2)
            (setq seconds (+ seconds (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
          (setq minutes (+ minutes (string-to-number (match-string 1)))))))
    (insert (format "%d'%d''"(+ minutes (/ seconds 60)) (% seconds 60)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could it be modified to thread the case that the also format minutes' could occur?

Comment: @user406686: Sure thing, I updated the code to work with `minutes'`, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(defun add-times ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((mins 0) (secs 0) 
          (accum-nums 
           (lambda (regexp)
             (let ((value 0))
               (beginning-of-buffer)
               (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
                 (setq value (+ value (string-to-int (match-string-no-properties 1)))))
               value))))
      (setq mins (funcall accum-nums "\\([0-9]+\\)'\\([^']\\|$\\)"))
      (setq secs (funcall accum-nums "\\([0-9]+\\)''"))
      ; adjust > 60 seconds
      (setq mins (+ mins (/ secs 60)))
      (setq secs (mod secs 60))
      (format "%d'%d''" mins secs))))
```

And you can use it like this: In the buffer of the file with the times, you type <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> and then evaluate:

```
(insert (add-times))
```

If you want a function that does this also, asking for the buffer:

```
(defun insert-add-times-to-buffer-at-point (buffer)
  (interactive "BBuffer to add and insert times: ")
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (insert (add-times))))
```

Comment: Thanks. However it gives me: `setq: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`

Comment: Yes, sorry. Still not correct. I'll fix it as soon as I can find a computer :)

Comment: Fixed now. Hope this one works. There is a little problem with the specification, as numbers can have either minutes, seconds or both, and this is difficult to express with a regex, at least so easily. In this case, all the numbers can have an optional minutes mark, but they have to include seconds, even if they are 0"

Comment: Hm. 5'2'' and 2'1''
gives 10'3'' with your script!?

Comment: I just checked, and with that data, it gives me 7'3".

Comment: For my syntax I wanted two single quotation marks ' instead of a double quotation mark ". I thought this should be a minor modification of your code - I just replaced the \" in your code by ''. Then I get the described result. Now I tested it with your original code and also with double quotation marks in my example, then I get the correct result.

Comment: OK, I see. You should be using monospaced font to signal those special characters to be better distinguishable. With double single quotes things are more difficult because one expression is a subexpression of the other. I'll change the code accordingly

Comment: @Diego Sevilla: Hi Diego, I believe your code will not work for cases where a minutes-only expression appears at the very end the buffer (no further whitespace), right?