# Add times in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, lisp, elisp

Some time ago, I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242960/add-times-in-buffer) how to add times in an emacs-buffer. Now the same thing to be displayed on an ikiwiki page. So the times to add are on the page where the added time should show up. Perhaps the best way would be to have the function in javascript. So my question is, if someone could translate the answer to my elisp question to javascript. The elisp code is:

```
  (defun add-times ()                 
  (interactive)                                
  (let ((minutes 0) (seconds 0))     
    (save-excursion                        
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\([0-9]+\\)'\\('\\)?" (point-max) t)
        (if (match-string 2)
            (setq seconds (+ seconds (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
          (setq minutes (+ minutes (string-to-number (match-string 1)))))))
    (insert (format "%d'%d''"(+ minutes (/ seconds 60)) (% seconds 60)))))
```

Comment: Ah, I forget how khhhhm... peculiar Lisp is.

Comment: ewww, that's lisp? /me runs away

Comment: It might frighten people less if you included only the date calculation part and skipped the buffery bits--which should be in its own function anyway. That part is only a couple lines and consists only of string -> conversion and trivial math.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```js
var seconds = function (str) {
    var m = /\d+(?=')/.exec(str);
    var s = /\d+(?=")/.exec(str);
    return (s ? parseInt(s[0], 10)      : 0) +
           (m ? parseInt(m[0], 10) * 60 : 0);
}

var totalTime = function (strs) {
    var totalSecs = strs.reduce(function (total, str) {
        return seconds(str) + total;
    }, 0);
    var m = Math.floor(totalSecs / 60);
    var s = totalSecs - (m * 60);
    return (m ? m + "'"  : "") +
           (s ? s + "\"" : "");
}

totalTime(["5'30\"", "6'15\"", "10'", "1\""]) // 21'46"
```

Comment: I fixed the syntax highlighting (you can put a `<!-- language: lang-js -->` before the code to choose the highlighting).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never knew about that feature before.

Comment: Thanks. However there is a last step missing, and I don't know how to do it by myself: Your function seems to want the times as argument, however I want that the function searches all visible content (not comments or code) of the html-page (where this javascript code should be embedded) for the times and display the result on the same page.

Comment: That step depends on the structure of the HTML.  You can see some examples of using Javascript to deal with information in HTML here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ex_dom.asp Many people use jQuery to make that part easier.